# Get current Item from Custom Field in Sitecore 6.5

Tags: sitecore, custom-fields

I am building a custom Field in sitecore 6.5. This field will generate new items based on the item in which the field resides (it uses the item's name to generate folders) and I need to reference the item in which the field is being used. How do I get access to this?

My custom field inherits from the sitecore Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.File class, if that helps at all.

My question is similar to the one located here: [How to get a reference to the currently edited item when inside a custom field in Sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148279/how-to-get-a-reference-to-the-currently-edited-item-when-inside-a-custom-field-i)

However, the question there was for a previous version of sitecore, and the solutions no longer seem to work (ItemID is not in the viewstate, nor is it filled by the pipeline).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, `Sitecore.Data.Fields.FileField` is a representation of the field's data in the Sitecore API. For instance, you would use it to retrieve the `MediaItem` or `Src` by casting an item's field like so:

```
var fieldSrc = ((FileField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["My File Field"]).Src;
```

I don't think it's intended to be used as a custom field in the Sitecore client. Try inheriting from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.File` or just strait up `Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control`. As long as you have a `public string ItemID { get; set; }` property defined, Sitecore should populate it with the current item ID.

Comment: Sorry, I need to update my question, I am inheriting from  Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.File - which does not have a public string ItemID in it's inheritance chain from what I can make out using ILSpy.

Comment: Inheriting from the base Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control and building all the functions that I needed from there seemed to work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Struggling with the same problem for several hours, I ended up decompiling EditorFormatter and found that this class has Method called SetProperties.

By reflection (!?) this method checks if your field editor has the properties "ItemID", "ItemVersion", "ItemLanguage" .... *sigh*

Ok, so by adding a public property 'ItemID' we have the item being edited